# Issue with 'Realize Instances' causing point rotations to change [Geometry Nodes]

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I've recently come across a strange issue, and have found nothing online suggesting as to what it could be that's causing it. I've spent a few days trying workarounds but with no success...

As part of a larger node setup for a growing flower, when I realize the petal instancers, their point directions change compared to before realizing. The problem this causes is that the petals have different starting and ending rotations compared to each other, which means they overlap and clip through each other. I've noticed this only happens when the petal instancers have been realized and aren't vertical?

[image: gif of issue]

As you can see in this gif here, the issue is only prominent when the pentagonal instancer isn't vertical. This is when the realize instances node starts changing the base instancers values.

[image: displacement gif]

I need to use the realize instances node so that the petals can be controlled independently from each other. Without it, all petals open at the same time defeating the effect of a progressively growing flower branch.

I've tried various vector operators to try reset the rotation, or transfer the point rotations from before the realization without any luck. I've recreated the effect in a new file. Node tree below...

[image]

In summary, I need the realized petals to have the same starting/ending rotation on a non-vertical instancer. Any help or solutions, or a different approach to achieve the same result would be hugely appreciated. Thanks!

The file can be downloaded [here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bsF065zuzlO2dvGytQTVa7n2RU5e5wp8/view?usp=share_link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the tilt of your first curve, you have to control it and straight it up, like this:

[image]

I hope it help.

[image]

Comment: Thank you loads! You just solved 3 days of my time with some vector maths